# Which Sitecore pipelines execute between renderLayout and renderField?

Tags: sitecore

I’m looking into a performance issue with Sitecore 8 where I'm loosing ~25 seconds after *renderLayout* and before the *renderField* pipeline. Anyone have any clues which pipeline(s) is execute between them? Or any ideas how to debug this?

Thanks

Comment: Add sc_debug=1 to your URL of your slow page, once logged in to Sitecore. You'll be able to see all the renderings that get loaded in at the bottom of the page. Which one has the slowest load time?

Comment: You could also check pipeline execution using the profiler in `/sitecore/admin/Pipelines.aspx`, you'll need to enable _Sitecore.PipelineProfiling.config_ though.

Comment: I think this is more a case of looking at what the pipelines are doing. In this case, executing your codebase. Your first port of call should probably be looking at your codebase rather than the pipeline system steps.

Answer (score 1):

You can check the Show Config file.

Path: /sitecore/admin/showconfig.aspx.

You will be able to see all the configurations and in which order they are being triggered. Also, you can disable the SPEAK precompilation.

You can read on the following: http://www.sitecore.net/learn/blogs/technical-blogs/john-west-sitecore-blog/posts/2015/02/maximize-sitecore-developer-productivity.aspx

Thanks